# Копирование данных пользователя

Tags: phpmyadmin, php

Здравствуйте.

Уже полмесяца роюсь в Интернете, не нашел решения своей проблемы. Есть база данных, в ней две таблицы одинаковые по структуре, я организую турнир, и мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку данные пользователя, который нажал на кнопку, копировались в другую таблицу. Написал этот код:

```
<?php
include_once("bd.php");
{ 
  $query = "INSERT INTO uchastniki SELECT * FROM users  ";
  mysql_query ( $query ); 
  echo 'Вы успешно зарегестрировались';
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Но тут проблема в том, что он копирует все записи, а мне нужны данные только того пользователя, который кликнул на кнопку. И ещё нужно сделать так, чтобы во вторую таблицу не могло попасть более 16 пользователей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO uchastniki SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = `$USER`
```

А про макс число пользователей.
Делаете запрос на подсчёт кол-ва строк в бд.

```
if($bd->count() > 16){
 echo "Мест нет";
}
```

Comment: $user - это и есть переменная, в которой передаётся ник-нейм пользователя.

Comment: WHERE `колонка` = `данные с колонки`
$bd->count() - это я образно написал.
Под этим я хотел Вам показать, что надо сделать выорку из бд сколько данных в ней находится.

Comment: `$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  'ТАБЛИЦА'"); 
$posts = mysql_result($result);
//echo $posts;`
$posts в данном случае кол-во записей в бд.

Comment: UPD <<<
`
<?php 
include_once("bd.php");  //подключение дб
{
$query = "INSERT INTO uchastniki SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = $login"; //регистрация пользователя
mysql_query ( $query ); 
echo 'Вы успешно зарегестрировались'; }

$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'uchastniki'"); //кол-во записей в бд
$posts = mysql_result($result); 
echo $posts; //кол-во участников 
if($posts < 16){ 

#добавляем юзера

} else {
echo "Нету свободных мест";
}

mysql_close(); 

?> 
`
P.s. Не могу комментировать :(

Comment: Вам нужно будет добавить в БД еще один столбец, в котором будет храниться имя пользователя а для этого нужно будет регистрировать каждого пользователя или же записывать в этот столбец номер сессии, который будет идентичным каждый раз или же можно айпи адрес писать в этот столбец и после этого можно будет уже дописать  в запрос "where userip = '255.151.15.154'

Comment: По сути, у меня для каждого стоит свой id, он не повторяется, и у каждого он уникален, как я понимаю, если прописать "where userip = '255.151.15.154'", то он будет копировать только определённого пользователя, а мне именно нужно, чтобы любой пользователь из одной таблицы копировался в другую при нажатии на кнопку. Может, в bd.php нужно сессии запустить?

Comment: а в чем проблема сделать так $query = "INSERT INTO uchastniki SELECT * FROM users where id= '845 ";

Comment: а в чем проблема сделать так $query = "INSERT INTO uchastniki SELECT * FROM users where id= '845 "; если сделать так, то, как я понимаю, он будет копировать только пользователя с id = 845, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Да так и есть это условие для выборки из бд погуглите